# How to use 2 different res folders inside a Jar File

Tags: java, jar, imageicon

I have a program that runs perfectly in Eclipse. The tree looks something like this:

```
PROGRAM
--SRC
----all my java files...
--res1
---- null.jpg
--res2
---- null.jpg
```

The two null.jpg's are different, but when I try to move to a `jar` file, they are combined and then I cannot use them like I normally call them. Is there some way that I could create `res` folders inside the `jar` file allowing me to access my files normally?

Also to get the pictures I am using this code within my program:

`Imageicon i = new ImageIcon("res1/null.jpg");`

(Yes I know the code above won't work for a jar file because they are moved from a res1 folder and into the null.jpg folder instead. I have attempted to use: 
 `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("null.jpg"));`, but that doesn't work for me...)

Also I cannot just use like null1, and null2 because I have something like 300 pictures. So that cannot be a solution for me...

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What does your jar file contain exactly? Give us the relevant part of the file tree inside the jar file.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure the structure of your project is the same as it will end up in your jar file. Than, if it works in eclipse, it will also work with the jar file.

So change your directory structure to something like this:

```
- src
- resources
  |- res1
  |  \- null.jpg
  \- res2
     \-null.jpg
```

Inside the code you can then reference it with `getClass().getResource("/res1/null.jpg")` or `/res2/` ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

What on earth is a "res" folder? Is it like src/main/resources in a Maven project?

Anyway, you just need to have folders within res, like this:

```
res/1
res/2
res/3
```

Alternatively you could write a script to bulk move all your null images into the same folder and rename them at the same time.